# HTML/CSS in Other Spoken languages?

Tags: html, css, spoken-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do people in non-English-speaking countries code in English?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english)

Do developers who don't natively speak English still code using english property and tag names? Like, would a Japanese front end web developer still need to know what border-radius means in English to use it, or would Japanese sites use Japanese CSS?

I ask because I'm an English speaking web developer who aspires to be multilingual someday, and I might try to use that combination of skills to travel the world a little. Will I still code in English, even while building sites in China or Japan? If so, would that improve my chances of getting a job?

Answer (score 4):

CSS properties and HTML entities are not localized.

A Japanese or Hebrew or any other language site would still use `<head>` and `<body>` elements in their HTML, and similarly in CSS.

Yes, they will need to understand what the characters `border-radius` end up meaning in terms of CSS and how they effect styling, even if they have no idea how to pronounce them or what their exact semantics are.

They will know that they need to use `<head>` for items that go into the HTML header, but they might not know and understand where the word `head` comes from and what it means in other contexts.